# I want to store the data received from serial port in a string variable that will be accessed in another class

Tags: java, rxtx

I want to store the data received from serial port in a string variable that will be accessed in another class. 
I wrote up code that prints the data received from com port but when the variable is accessed out of the method it returns `null`..
Please help me out.. I am using RxTx library for this.

```
public class ProtocolImpl implements Protocol {  

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  
    int tail = 0;  
    public String message;

    public void onReceive(byte b) {  
        // simple protocol: each message ends with new line  
        if (b=='\n') {  
            onMessage();  
        } else {  
            buffer[tail] = b;  
            tail++;  
        }  
    }  

    public void onStreamClosed() {  
        onMessage();  
    }  

    /* 
     * When message is recognized onMessage is invoked  
     */  
    private void onMessage() {  
        if (tail!=0) 
        {  
            // constructing message  
            message = getMessage(buffer, tail);  
            //rmess = message;
            System.out.println("RECEIVED MESSAGE: " + message);  

            if ("KITM".equalsIgnoreCase(message)) {  
                CommPortSender.send(getMessage("OK"));  
            } 
            tail = 0;  
        }  
    }  

    public String rmess() /*this method is returning null.. please help me out*/
    {
        if (tail!=0) {  
        message = getMessage(buffer, tail); 
        }
        return message;
    }

    // helper methods   
    public byte[] getMessage(String message) {  
        return (message).getBytes();  
    }  

    public String getMessage(byte[] buffer, int len) {  
        return new String(buffer, 0, tail);  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code with how you're attempting to access the variable "out of the method" where it returns `null`? Or indicate what part of the posted code is the part that's doing this?

Comment: if the rmess() method is called inside onmessage():
onMessage()
{
   ...........
   ..........
   System.out.println("RECEIVED MESSAGE: " + message);  
   System.out.println(rmess());
   .......
   .......
} 
 here it returns the value of the received message means both line gives same output (obviously) but when the rmess() method is called out of this class it returns null..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an [instance variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_variable) `message`.  There is one instance of this variable for each `ProtocolImpl` object.  Presumably the `ProtocolImpl` object on which `onMessage` is called is a different `ProtocolImpl` object on which `rmess` is called.

The easy fix is just to make `message` a [static variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable) so that there is only one instance of that variable in the whole program.  Be careful, though, this can cause some subtle problems like synchronization and object independence.  A better solution is to make sure you are using the same `ProtocolImpl` object to call both `onMessage` and `rmess`.

Comment: I don't wanna use the rmess() method i'm doing it just to get the value of the received message in a string so that i can use the variable out of the class.. the S.O.P. line in onMessage() method is printing the received message but i was unable to catch it so i created this return type method but this was a fail.. Lemme check the code by make the message variable static..

Comment: Keith Randall >>heyy thanks buddy, i made the message variable static.. and it worked.. thanks a lot... why didn't it came to my mind before :P

Answer (score 0):

Your message object is not serialized so you are getting message is null. You can implement java.io.Serializable